# Open files in VirtualBox Shared Folders to survive a Linux VM state save/restore

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

VirtualBox has Shared Folders (provided by the `vboxsf` kernel module in Linux VMs). When the VM is saved with a file in a mounted shared folder open, that file handle is lost (appears as `(deleted)` in `/proc/nn/fd`) when the VM is restored later. The process holding the open file handle continues to run as it would do with a deleted file on a local filesystem.
This behavior is different from a NFS file handle which is reopened automatically by the NFS driver after the connection to the NFS server is lost for some reason (wich may be a VM state save/restore).

**Is there anything I can do about that ?**
How can I detect the restore event inside the VM in order to reopen the file in question (by restarting the process or signalling it etc.) ?

Edit:
I'm using VirtualBox version 6.0.22 with the Guest additions that are part of the Linux kernel (here Ubuntu 18 LTS desktop with default kernel), but not the version that is delivered with VirtualBox's `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` file. I'm not using any of the GUI integration features but only the basic system level functions like shared files with `mount -t vboxsf ...`.

Comment: Have you installed Guest Additions and how? What is your VirtualBox version?

Comment: @harrymc, I'm editing the question.